# K8S + Helm. combine two values yamls files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using *K8S* with *Helm 3*.

Can I run command line `helm install myproject myproject/`, so it will use more than one `values.yaml` file, without providing it to the `helm install` command? - That should be by somehow link one `values.yaml` file to one main values file.

In *values.yaml*:

```
... myFile2: <link-to-values2.yaml>
```

Both the values from the files will be used.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to import files inside yaml files but you can specify multiple files in with -f in the helm command

Comment: This isnt going to work as Helm only takes the right most file if you specify multiple files